# Error while creating gke cluster in shared vpc gogle project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am getting following error when I am trying to create gke cluster in shared vpc project.

```
(gcloud.container.clusters.create) ResponseError: code=403, message=Kubernetes Engine Service Agent is missing required permissions on this project. See https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting#gke_service_account_deleted for more info: required "container.hostServiceAgent.use" permission(s) for "projects/host-project".
```

I tried disabling and enabling back the

```
gcloud services enable container.googleapis.com
```

Still no luck.

Comment: Service account was missing in host project

Comment: Your issue is solved now?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting#gke_service_account_deleted), When you activate the Kubernetes Engine API, Google Cloud creates the Google Kubernetes Engine service account with the Kubernetes Engine Service Agent role on your project. Based on the error message, it appears that the service account associated with GKE has been deleted or edited manually.

Additionally, if you modify those permissions, delete the role bindings on the project, remove the service account completely, or disable the API, then cluster creation and all management functionality will fail.